# Development on existing Umbraco-project

Tags: c#, .net, git, iis, umbraco

I have an existing Umbraco-project running on an IIS-server. When I started the project I basically installed Umbraco directly to the server and coded through the Admin-interface until the site was launched and went live.

Now, the customer wants some changes and it feels like I've painted myself into a corner here, since I obviously can't make changes in the code while the site is running. So, my question, which I hope this excellent community can help me out with:

How do I proceed when I get a copy of the project locally, to develop in Visual Studio and then publish it back to the live server? Should I create a GIT-repo, or is WebDeploy an option? Which workflow is the most convenient when developing and maintaining an Umbraco site?

I am also quite insecure about what configurations are needed on the IIS-server to support deployment from my local machine, so some input about that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Don't tell anyone, but for file updates only (like stylesheets or templates), I sometimes just FTP them up or publish to file system and copy/paste the files via RDP. If you make changes to document types etc., consider if you can't just test them locally and recreate the changes in the live environment afterwards.

Of course, this is only viable for small changes/solutions and one-man teams, but I feel that it's perfectly okay since the alternative(s) get very complex very quickly.

Edit: and also it requires you to keep your local copy pretty close to the live one, so you can be relatively sure stuff doesn't break when you "publish".

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to get a copy of the files from the server, but also use a local copy of the database and update the connection string in web.config to point to that, otherwise any backoffice changes you make will be made on the live server.

If you are just making changes to views then some kind of publish from visual studio will probably work, but if you are making new document types, macros etc., this also involves data changes in the database which won't be published from visual studio at the same time.

There are various tools out there which cater for this situation of making development changes and moving them to live.

The obvious one is that you repeat all the changes you made in dev on the live server, although this can become tedious if there are lots of changes.

There are also things like [Umbraco Courier](http://umbraco.com/products-and-support/courier/) and another one which I can't remember the name of for the life of me that copy all the relevant things from dev to live in one go.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of uSync? https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/usync/

Comment: Yeah, it could be. I haven't used uSync but I imagined it to be something that helped devs synchronise code changes when working in their own personal development environments with the own disparate SQL servers etc. as it requires a site restart. Whether that is an accurate view though is questionable.